# Refreshing page makes jQuery button click trigger twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have a star button that a user can click to star something on my site. When clicked it submits an ajax request and my rails controller handles the rest. The ajax works fine and I'm using some coffeescript and jQuery to change the star icon when it is clicked. It works fine, but if I refresh the page the click triggers twice. I have tried .preventDefault() but it does nothing. What works in stopping it from triggering twice is .stopImmediatePropagation(). This, however, changes my button from having a method of POST to GET and I get a routing error saying that there is no such route as GET/...

Here's my button:

```
<%= link_to star_question_path(@question), method: :post, remote: true do %>
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x fa-yellow" id="star-question-icon"></i>
<% end %>
```

Coffeescript and jQuery:

```
$('#star-question-icon').on 'click', (e) ->
  if $(this).hasClass "fa-star"
    $(this).removeClass('fa-star')
    $(this).addClass('fa-star-o')
  else if $(this).hasClass "fa-star-o"
    $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o')
    $(this).addClass('fa-star')
  return
```

This works but changes the method to GET if the page is refreshed:

```
$('#star-question-icon').on 'click', (e) ->
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  if $(this).hasClass "fa-star"
    $(this).removeClass('fa-star')
    $(this).addClass('fa-star-o')
  else if $(this).hasClass "fa-star-o"
    $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o')
    $(this).addClass('fa-star')
  return
```

My corresponding route:

```
post 'question/:id/star', to: 'questions#star', as: 'star_question'
```

Comment: Are you by chance using turbolinks? Check your gemfile and application.js to see if you are, it's typically included by default, and will cause the behavior you describe. Just remove it and you should be fine.

Comment: @DivXZero yes I am using turbolinks. Isn't it necessary? I thought it is

Comment: It's not, turbolinks basically makes your application into a single page app (similar to react), it only fetches the content for each page, but keeps the JS and such loaded between page requests. It's meant to improve performance, but it's negligible. The first thing I do on any new project is remove it, it doesn't really do anything but cause headaches.

Comment: @DivXZero Ok thanks I'll remove it

Comment: Not sure if I'm looking at regular JavaScript or not, but if I am, then you need to put `{` and `}` around your `if`/`else` blocks, otherwise only the first statement in the block will be conditionally executed and the others will always be executed. Maybe it's a CoffeeScript thing?

Comment: @ScottMarcus no it's coffeescript so it works like that

Comment: @DivXZero Yeah removing turbolinks fixed the issue - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Next code is blocking  a doubleclick.

```
   $document.on('click','#star-question-icon',function(ev){
        if(ev.detail>1){
          // this code execute after twice click or more
          return false;
        }
      });
```